# Formatting long string of text in PhpStorm

Tags: php, phpstorm

I want to format a long string of text in PhpStorm:

```
$query = echo 'This is a sample code'
```

When I press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to go to the next line or use Reformat Code (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>) to wrap long text, I would like the code to appear like this:

```
$query = echo 'This is 
               a sample code';
```

not:

```
$query = echo 'This is a
sample code'
```

Comment: Well, in that case `$query` would become `This is\n` + **15 spaces** + `a sample code`

Comment: that makes the process quite lengthy. Phpstorm has automatic code formatting with indents and nice code presentation this allows you to focus on writing the code

Answer (score 1):

You can do it, for example, like this:

```
$query = ''
    .'This is'
    .' '
    .'a sample code';
```

This is a bit tricky, but I also do not know how to do this in the other way.